# How to pass props through Link

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Fairly new to react here.  I'm making a small recipe finder app with an api.  After getting the data, I'm mapping through the results and displaying them in a component.  What I want to do is display the details of each recipe through another component in another route.  I'm not sure how to do this.  I thought I could pass the mapped recipe through Link, but it's not working.  Here is what I have so far.

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import RecipeList from "./RecipeList";
import Recipe from "./Recipe";
import Header from "./Header";

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const APP_ID = "XXXXXXXXX";
  const APP_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  const url = `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2?type=public&q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`;

  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const res = await axios(url);
    const data = await res.data.hits;
    console.log(data);
    setRecipes(data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
  }, [query]);

  const updateSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    console.log(search);
  };

  const getSearchQuery = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
    setSearch("");
    navigate("/recipes");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <form className="search-form" onSubmit={getSearchQuery}>
            <input
              className="search-input"
              type="text"
              value={search}
              onChange={updateSearch}
              placeholder="search by food name"
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/recipes" element={<RecipeList recipes={recipes} />} />
          <Route path="/recipes/:id" element={<Recipe recipes={recipes} />}/>
        </Routes>
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

RecipeList.jsx

```
import React from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const RecipeList = ({ recipes }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="grid-container">
        {recipes.map(({ recipe }) => (
          <Link to={`/recipes/${recipe.label}`}>
            <img key={recipe.image} src={recipe.image} alt="" />
            <p key={recipe.label}>{recipe.label}</p>
            <p>{recipe.id}</p>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RecipeList;
```

Recipe.jsx

```
const Recipe = ({recipe}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{recipe.label}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Recipe
```

Am I even close???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the entire `recipes` array to both routed components.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/recipes" element={<RecipeList recipes={recipes} />} />
  <Route path="/recipes/:id" element={<Recipe recipes={recipes} />}/>
</Routes>
```

So `Recipe` can use the entire array and the `id` route match param to search the passed array and render the exact recipe by matching `label`.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Recipe = ({ recipes }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const recipe = recipes.find(recipe => recipe.label === id); // *

  return recipe ? (
    <div>
      <h1>{recipe.label}</h1>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};
```

*** Note:** Since you call the route param `id` it may make more sense to us the `recipe.id` for the link.

```
{recipes.map(({ recipe }) => (
  <Link to={`/recipes/${recipe.id}`}>
    <img key={recipe.image} src={recipe.image} alt="" />
    <p key={recipe.label}>{recipe.label}</p>
    <p>{recipe.id}</p>
  </Link>
))}
```

...

```
const recipe = recipes.find(recipe => recipe.id === id);
```

Comment: Hey Drew, thanks for the help on this again!  There actually isn't any id in this api that I could find.  I just used :id because that's what I typically would use.  Sorry, should have been more clear.

Comment: @RRhodes No worries. Any unique property value that easily stringifies to the URL should work.